# What is the bootstrap folder inside laravel for?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I recently learning laravel and as I go along I decided to include bootstrap for my styling and `js`. I found a bootstrap folder inside my laravel folder and I am confused if bootstrap is already included in laravel. If that is so, where are the bootstrap `css` and `js` files? What kind of call am I going place inside my html? Hope someone could clarify this to me. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The bootstrap folder is for when Laravel starts up. Which is commonly called bootstrapping.  It has nothing to do with the Bootstrap CSS library.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel's bootstrap folder has nothing to do with the `Bootstrap CSS framework`, it's used to initialize (setting up path & environments) the framework.

Answer (score 2):

The bootstrap directory contains the app.php file which bootstraps the framework. This directory also houses a cache directory which contains framework generated files for performance optimization such as the route and services cache files and like the others says there is no relation between this folder and the css framework .

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you do npm install and then go to the node_modules folder, you'll find the bootstrap folder there. And inside it there will be scss and js folders.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap folder has nothing to do with CSS, it comes from bootstraping (the self-start process) and it contains files that automatically load the classes to boot up the start of the project, and this process starts automatically without any external intervention.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap directory holds the files that are required to bootstrap the Laravel application and to configure auto-loading. The bootstrap folder contains a sub-folder cache used for caching a web application. It also contains the file app.